# How do I add different colors to each word in a hyperlink in HTML?

Tags: html, css

The exact question was : Write an HTML program which includes a single hyperlink containing three words with each word displayed in a different color. Eg: "JavaScript WebProgramming CSS" (JavaScript in green, WebProgramming in red, CSS in yellow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as easy as this!

```
<a href="https://so.com"><x style="color:green">JavaScript</x> <x style="color:red">WebProgramming</x> <x style="color:yellow">CSS</x></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `"<span></span>"`

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="green">JavaScript</span> 
  <span class="red">WebProgramming</span> 
  <span class="yellow">CSS</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#m1{
color:red;
}
#m2{
color:green;
}
#m3{
color:pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span id="m1">Webprogram</span><span id="m2">Javascript</span><span id="m3">CSS</span></a>
```

Comment: Question is easy ! if you have seen first you would be faster than me

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the text colors of anchor tag directly. I can suggest to create separate span in it and specify colors as follows:

```
<style>
.chngColor {
  color: blue;
 }
 </style>

<a href='#'><span class='chngColor'>Hello</span> World!</a>
```

Comment: Much faster than Gowtham

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#"><span style="color:green">JavaScript</span> <span style="color:red">WebProgramming</span> <span style="color:yellow">CSS</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code for u. this will give u a general idea of making link in different colors
**e.g.**

```
<p><span style="color: #0000ff;">&nbsp;</span><a title="padfoot" href="http://www.google.com"><span style="color: #0000ff;">javastring</span> <span style="color: #ff0000;">css</span> <span style="color: #ff6600;">java</span></a></p>
```

Comment: <p><span style="color: #0000ff;">&nbsp;</span><a title="padfoot"
 href="http://www.google.com"><span style="color: #0000ff;">javastring</span> <span style="color: #ff0000;">css</span> <span style="color: #ff6600;">java</span></a></p>

Comment: Be careful Gowtham. if external link you must have protocol in URL